# Reason for using intermediate variable insteading of just returning result of expression?

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic question. I'm learning Javascript, and I'm fairly new to programming in general. In a lot of tutorials, I've seen something like this:

```
function add(a,b) {
    var sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}
```

Now, for such a simple calculation, it seems to me that there's no reason to create an intermediate variable. Rather, my instinct would be to do this:

```
 function add(a,b) {
    return a+b; 
}
```

I can understand the rationale for using intermediate variables if I'm doing a more complex calculation with multiple steps, and of course they're necessary for conditionals. Are these tutorials just trying to inculcate habits for readable code when things get more complicated, or is there a reason why the first example is inherently better? It seems like there's a memory performance cost in doing it the first way. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

I've searched SO and also googled it, but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Using intermediate variables can help with debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use things like this often to make debugging easier. That way I can see exactly what the return value will be before stepping out of a function.

Also it makes scaleability much easier as, you can have more variables flying around before returning a value.

Don't be cheap when it comes to using variables, else you'll pay for it later. Of course I mean in cases more complex than your example.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was something right under my nose - I've even used this technique before; I just didn't make the connection to such a simple example. But perhaps it's just a good habit to do this by default. I guess it's a judgment call as to when something is simple enough that it's not likely to need debugging. Out of curiosity, just how much of a performance trade-off is there?

Comment: @bencohenbaritone: none, that is none that matters.

Answer (score 7):

You're not missing anything. Your instinct is correct - there is no need for the intermediate variable.